# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, video, filter, gpu, exoplayer

I'm unable to add a new view to the viewgroup.

It's throwing error:

> AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

I am referring [this](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android) library

I am able to show the player view with out filter and recyclerview, if I'm using like below. binding.playerView.setPlayer(player) in the play() method without 'gpuPlayerView'. In this case my activity_view.xml is which is working with Exoplayer's PlayerView.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.test.view.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/player_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:controller_layout_id="@layout/item_player_controler"
                app:resize_mode="fill"
                app:show_timeout="1000"
                app:shutter_background_color="@color/black" />
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/black_55"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:onClick="@{onBackClick}"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                    android:tint="@color/white" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/popins_reguler"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Preview" />
    
            </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

But problem begin from here if I am replacing the above 'xml' file with the below one and adding steps related to 'gpuPlayerView.setSimpleExoPlaye' etc:

activity_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.view.MainActivity">
   
    <com.broadmind.clipps.filter.MovieWrapperView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_movie_wrapper"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/fifty_transparent_black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ActivityPreviewBinding binding;
    private MainViewModel viewModel;
    private CustomDialogBuilder customDialogBuilder;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    GPUPlayerView gpuPlayerView;
    public static int  select_postion=0;
    final List<FilterType> filterTypes = FilterType.createFilterList();
    Filter_Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recylerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_view);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ViewModelFactory(new MainViewModel()).createFor()).get(MainViewModel.class);
        customDialogBuilder = new CustomDialogBuilder(this);
        viewModel.sessionManager = sessionManager;
        initView();
        play();
        initObserve();
        //initListener();
    }


    private void initView() {
        viewModel.vidPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("send_video_path");
    }

    private void play() {

        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
              Util.getUserAgent(this, "MyApp"));

        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(viewModel.vidPath));



        player.prepare(videoSource);
        player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
        player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
        player.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters.DEFAULT);
        //player.addListener(this);
        //binding.playerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

       
        gpuPlayerView = new GPUPlayerView(this);
        gpuPlayerView.setPlayerScaleType(PlayerScaleType.RESIZE_NONE);

        gpuPlayerView.setSimpleExoPlayer(player);
        gpuPlayerView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        
        MovieWrapperView rl = (MovieWrapperView) findViewById(R.id.layout_movie_wrapper);
        rl.addView(gpuPlayerView);


        gpuPlayerView.onResume();

        recylerview=findViewById(R.id.recylerview);

        adapter = new Filter_Adapter(this, filterTypes, new Filter_Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int postion, FilterType item) {
                select_postion=postion;
                gpuPlayerView.setGlFilter(FilterType.createGlFilter(filterTypes.get(postion), getApplicationContext()));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        recylerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recylerview.setAdapter(adapter); 

    }

   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```